# DAX equivalent of GROUP BY CUBE()

Tags: dax

I'm using SUMMARIZE(...ROLLUP...) in DAX which accomplishes the same as a
GROUP BY ROLLUP() in T-SQL and so far so good.

Is there a DAX statement that will do the same as 
GROUP BY CUBE()?  I want to get all the other permutations of rollup as well.

Here is a mocked up example, hopefully it will make sense

```
 EVALUATE SUMMARIZE(Invoices , ROLLUP( [Customer], [Product], [Year]) ,
 "Orders", DISTINCTCOUNT(Invoices[Order ID]) )
```

Will return these segments

```
Customer Product        Year
NULL     NULL           NULL
Smith    NULL           NULL
Smith    Bikes          NULL
Smith    Bikes          2015
Smith    Bikes          2016
Smith    Treadmills     NULL
Smith    Treadmills     2015
Smith    Treadmills     2016
```

But what I want to see is

```
Customer Product        Year
NULL     NULL           NULL
Smith    NULL           NULL
NULL     Bikes          NULL
Smith    Bikes          NULL
NULL     Bikes          2015
NULL     Bikes          2016
NULL     Treadmills     2015
NULL     Treadmills     2016
NULL     NULL           2015
NULL     NULL           2016
Smith    Bikes          2015
Smith    Bikes          2016
NULL     Treadmills     NULL
Smith    Treadmills     NULL
Smith    Treadmills     2015
Smith    Treadmills     2016
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but think you can use a mix of ADDCOLUMNS, SUMMARIZE and ROLLUP to get the same output generated by CUBE. What is your data and your expected table?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added an example to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate three different tables using `ROLLUP` multple times to mimic the cube granularity.

`ROLLUP ( [Customer], [Product], [Year] )`
`ROLLUP ( [Product], [Year], [Customer] )`
`ROLLUP ( [Year], [Customer], [Product] )`

While this generates three tables, it is necessary to `UNION` them and remove duplicates from the final table since it repeats some total and subtotals rows so you have to use `DISTINCT` function.

The final DAX expression should be this:

```
EVALUATE
DISTINCT (
    UNION (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Invoices,
                ROLLUP ( [Customer], [Product], [Year] ),
                "Orders", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Invoices[Order ID] )
            ),
            "Customer", [Customer],
            "Product", [Product],
            "Year", [Year],
            "Orders", [Orders]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Invoices,
                ROLLUP ( [Product], [Year], [Customer] ),
                "Orders", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Invoices[Order ID] )
            ),
            "Customer", [Customer],
            "Product", [Product],
            "Year", [Year],
            "Orders", [Orders]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Invoices,
                ROLLUP ( [Year], [Customer], [Product] ),
                "Orders", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Invoices[Order ID] )
            ),
            "Customer", [Customer],
            "Product", [Product],
            "Year", [Year],
            "Orders", [Orders]
        )
    )
)
```

The final result should be something like this:

```
Customer    Product     Year    Orders
 Smith       Bikes      2015      2
 Smith       Bikes      2016      2
 Smith     Treadmills    2016     1
 Smith       Bikes                4
 Smith     Treadmills             1
 Smith                            5
                                  5
             Bikes      2015      2
             Bikes      2016      2
           Treadmills    2016     1
             Bikes                4
           Treadmills             1
 Smith                  2015      2
 Smith                  2016      3
                        2015      2
                        2016      3
```

Let me know if this helps.